# Why am I getting blank lines

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm iterating through a $_POST to write each item into a text file. It's working, but despite having used 'strlen' to avoid blank lines, I'm still getting some. Can anyone tell me why? Here's my code:

```
$entries = "";
$filename = "test.txt";
foreach($_POST as $value) {
    if( is_array( $value ) ) {
        foreach( $value as $subvalue ) {
            if (strlen($subvalue) > 5) {
                $entries .= $subvalue . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
}
file_put_contents($filename, $entries);
```

Comment: please add `var_export` for `$_POST`; and `trim()` removes whitespaces at beginning and end if you need that

Comment: Are you getting blank lines or lines containing only whitespace? Maybe you want to try using `trim()` before counting the `strlen()`?

Comment: Also, if a certain `$subvalue` has a newline character at the end, then you add an additional one which would lead to blank lines. You might want to check for that as well.

Comment: trim() did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for your solution:

```
$entries = "";
$filename = "test.txt";
foreach($_POST as $value) {
    if( is_array( $value ) ) {
        foreach( $value as $subvalue ) {
            if (strlen(trim($subvalue)) > 5) {
                $entries .= $subvalue . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
}
file_put_contents($filename, $entries);
```